# Script html php

Tags: php, html

In the script below, I currently have a fixed value in the array of $out variable. Example: $out[**1**]. What I need is for this fixed value (in this case 1), to be replaced by the **str** value of the function.

str is javascript

$out[1] is php

Someone can help me?

```
<script>
    function teste2(str) {
        var xhttp;    
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("cli").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                   document.getElementById("resimg").innerHTML =
                   "<img src=" + "<?php echo ("img/base/".$out[1]);?>" + ">"   
             }
        };
    xhttp.open("GET", "clique.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what does `clique.php` return / echo as response? You ought to add that script to the question as that is where the answer lies mainly

Comment: Hi and welcome. My advice is to not mix js and php like this. What is your function goal ? How will you use this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, it doesn't make sense why you are mixing PHP in your JS. If you need data from the server side usable by your client side JS, there are multiple approaches.

1. The preferred approach is to make an API endpoint you can call and return JSON.
2. Another approach (not recommended) is to output a JSON object in a script tag on server render and then access it like:

```html
<script>
    let data = <?php echo(json_encode($myData)); ?>;
</script>
```

To answer your question though, you can set the value with JS since the variable you want is client side:

```js
function teste2(str) {
    var xhttp;    
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("cli").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let src = 'img/base/' + str;
            document.getElementById("resimg").innerHTML = '<img src="' + src + '">';   
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "clique.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP scripts run on the server side, while Javascript ones run on the client's browser.

Therefore, the value of `str` will only be resolved at runtime, when the function is called on the user's browser. There is no way for your PHP script to know in advance what the value will be, as your PHP script runs before any JS does.

I am sorry, but I believe you should re-imagine your design here.

**Edit:** I assume your `$out` is a PHP variable, right?